# error when running cmd flutter build ipa since android studio update

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I recently updated android studio to Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 and the followed by updating Flutter and all of its packages.
previously, when I ran flutter build ipa in the terminal in android studio, it would build my apps .ipa without any trouble. now that I've updated android studio I'm getting the below error when i run flutter build ipa.

`development@NC-MBP my_app % flutter build ipa

Archiving com.crossfiregames.my_app...
Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: NC (XKJ4653QSG)"
Running pod install...                                             299ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
[!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:108:in `compute_targets'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer/target_inspector.rb:40:in `compute_results'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1197:in `block (3 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1195:in `block (2 levels) in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `each'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1193:in `block in inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1188:in `inspect_targets_to_integrate'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:107:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.1/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

Error running pod install`

I tried searching for the error that it is giving me, [!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.

but cannot find much info about it. has anyone had this trouble before? and if so, how do i go ahead and fix it please? I'm new to flutter and this is beyond me.

thanks so much

Comment: it has something to do with google mobile ads. I went back to a previous version of the app and tried the building the .ipa and it worked! I then went through the missing dependencies and ran the build after each one and it failed after adding google_mobile_ads have no idea how to fix this though because my app needs these ads.

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76247185/unable-to-find-a-target-named-runnertests-in-project-runner-xcodeproj help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out how to fix it. in the podfile, you need to find the below text,

```
    target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_macos_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
#   target 'RunnerTests' do
#     inherit! :search_paths
#   end
end
```

and then comment out (#) the parts that are commented out. then it will build as usual

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I typically `flutter clean`.

If that doesn't work, `rm -r ios` and `flutter create --platforms=ios`, which recreates the iOS directory. If you still can't build, please file an issue at [github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose)

Comment: hi, that hasn't worked. when i run the flutter create part it returns the error No option specified for the output directory.

Comment: you specify a directory at the end, e.g. `flutter create --platforms=ios .`

Comment: Hi, sorry, how is the command supposed to look? I tried flutter create --platforms=ios /Users/my_computer/Development/apps/my_app and got the error: "my_app" is not a valid Dart package name.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757656/i-am-getting-the-following-error-on-running-flutter-create-my-appname-my-appna for more info on this error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, it seems that there is an issue with the project CocoaPods configuration. In this case, let's try the following steps:

- From the terminal, in the root directory of the project run

  ```
  pod repo update
  ```

  <sub>*In case of not having CocoaPods installed, run `sudo gem install cocoapods`*.</sub>

- Next, reinstall the CocoaPods dependencies, by running the following commands:

  ```
  rm ios/Podfile.lock
  rm -rf ios/Pods
  pod install --project-directory=ios
  ```

They remove the existing `Podfile.lock` file, the "Pods" directory thus reinstalling the CocoaPods dependencies.

Finally, run `flutter build ipa`.

Comment: thanks so much. followed your instructions and it took me back to my first problem of the error: Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to find a target named `RunnerTests` in project `Runner.xcodeproj`, did find `Runner`.
when running: pod install --project-directory=ios